# CSS - How to place div side by side with no space at left and right

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with multiple child div, I want to make the child div float side by side 4 per row.

floating rule must:

1. each child div same width.
2. 4 child div per row.
3. each row left side and right side must close with wrapper(0px/no space), like diagram below.
4. each row between each child div must have a space and must be same size, like diagram below.

[image]

by using css/css3 is posible to done it? sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS3 this is relatively easy: using `box-sizing: border-box;`, the width of the child div will be including padding (e.g. `20px`) and border, and can be set to 25% of the width the body. Give the parent div, the wrapper, a negative right-margin to hide the rightmost space. Due to that extra space, a scroll bar will appear on the body which can be hidden with `overflow-x: hidden;`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  margin-right: -20px;
}
.child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.child p {
  background: lime;   
}
```

```html
<p>Content</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child"><p>Child</p></div>
  <div class="child"><p>Child</p></div>
  <div class="child"><p>Child</p></div>
  <div class="child"><p>Child</p></div>
</div>
<p>Content</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty nice examples out here, however I'd always want to have a look at a way to have my images aligned with my text. To do this I've been using a page wrapper and an image wrapper with a negative margin (to place it out of line with the text). Then after applying that same value as a positive padding value, the images are perfectly aligned with the text.

```
#pagewrapper {
    width: 500px;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#imagewrapper {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 -12px; /* negative margin to keep images aligned with text, same as margin below */
    background: blue;
}

.image {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 12px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/te2ccpqd/1/)

Comment: really thank for replay,see this link :) [http://jsfiddle.net/dzLt8xjj/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/dzLt8xjj/3/) i want to remove the space

Comment: Thank friend!! you fixed my problem!

Comment: It's quite different from my code ;). You should combine `box-sizing: border-box` with `width: 25%`, otherwise the inner div will be too short and there will be some space left.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw, @user2782378 answer.. i think i should elaborate on this by giving my answer:

```
div{float:left;width:20%;background:black;height:100px;margin:1px;}
```

[Js fiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ytu8g92r/)

For studying the css used:

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:inline-block` modify child div's width proportionally

```
.outer_div{
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:800px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  overflow:auto;
}
.inner_div{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:black;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this pure CSS2 solution is preferable.

A `div` is a block element which defaults to the page's width. If you give the wrapper div a right margin of three times the margin between the inner div's, then 25% of the wrapper width is exactly the width of the inner div. Adjust for the location of the inner divs with relative positioning:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.wrapper div {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: lime; /* demo setting */
    height: 100px;    /* demo setting */
}
.wrapper div+div {
    left: 10px;
}
.wrapper div+div+div {
    left: 20px;
}
.wrapper div+div+div+div {
    left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; // center the content of the container
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block; // display inline with abality to provide width/height
}​
```

- having margin: 0 auto; along with width: 100% is useless because you element will take the full space.
- float: left will float the elements on the left, until there is no space left, thus they will go on a new line. Use display: inline-block to be able to display elements inline, burt with the ability to provide size (compared to display inline where width/height are ignored)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZB9z/509/)

Comment: really thank for replay,see this link :) [http://jsfiddle.net/dzLt8xjj/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/dzLt8xjj/3/). i want to remove the space